# Why C++ biased towards destructor's exception?

Tags: c++, exception, compiler-construction, destructor

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Cls
{
public:
    ~Cls()
    {
        throw "exp";
    }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        Cls   c;
        throw "exp";
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        cout << "Why this doesn't call" << endl;
    }
}
```

When I execute this code, it doesn't goes in catch block. And give following exception,
[image]

But, when I run this code with little modification, it goes to catch block.

```
int main()
{
    try
    {
        throw "exp";
        throw "exp";
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        cout << "Why this doesn't call" << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:
[image]

Both the above code throws 2 exception, then why Compiler is biased in destructor's case?

Comment: because in destructor's case there is no catch..?

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 So that exception will flow to calling function.

Comment: indeed, but i can't figure out anything else so far..

Comment: Because a throwing destructor complicates logic as well as the underlying implementation of exception handling?

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/dtors-shouldnt-throw.html

Comment: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?BewareOfExceptionsInTheDestructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case you first throw from the `try` block and then the stack unwinding throws from `Cls`'s destructor. So you have two exceptions to be handled. C++ handles this situation by calling `terminate`.

Because of the peculiarity of throwing from destructors, C++11 defines that all destructors are `noexcept` by default. Then even if there is no other exception to be handled, the exception from a destructor will cause `terminate` to be called.

The second case is OK because as soon as you throw the first exception `try` block is left and the exception is handled in the `catch` block.

Comment: +1. Great. How fool I am not to understand simple thing.

Comment: @pranitkothari: You can handle this event by setting your terminate function, see [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr153.htm)